# Converting a TXT file to an encrypted PDF file

Tags: python, fpdf, pypdf

I am trying to convert a text file(.txt) to an encrypted PDF file but I get an error:

`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Inside the text file(.txt) is Chinese text and the code I am using is below:

```
import PyPDF2
from fpdf import FPDF


with open('Chinese.txt') as f:
   QQ = f.read()    
   QQ = QQ.encode('utf-8')

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_xy(0, 0)
pdf.set_font('arial', 'B', 13.0)
pdf.cell(40,10,QQ)
pdf.output('Before.pdf', 'F')



pdffile = open(r"Before.pdf", "rb")
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdffile)
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pdfWriter.addPage(pdfReader.getPage(pageNum))


pdfWriter.encrypt('123')
resultPDF = open(r"After.pdf", "wb")
pdfWriter.write(resultPDF)
resultPDF.close()
pdffile.close()
```

Comment: For everyone else: the problem is on the line `pdf.cell(40,10,QQ)`

Comment: It works in python 2

Comment: Look for the relation of type 'bytes' and 'str', and notice the difference of this relation between Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer
  I have Chinese font in the Chinese.txt that's why couldn't convert to PDF successfully,
so need to download fireflysung.ttf to support Chinese display in PDF.

```
import PyPDF2
from fpdf import FPDF

with open'Chinese.txt') as f:
    QQ = f.read()

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.add_font('fireflysung', '', 'fireflysung.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.set_font('fireflysung', '', 12)
pdf.set_xy(0, 0)

pdf.multi_cell(0,5,QQ) 
pdf.output('Before.pdf', 'F')


with open("Before.pdf", "rb") as pdffile:
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdffile)
    pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
        pdfWriter.addPage(pdfReader.getPage(pageNum))

    pdfWriter.encrypt(a)
    with open("After.pdf", "wb") as resultPDF:
        pdfWriter.write(resultPDF)
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you don't need to encode utf-8, since FPDF does for you. please apply below changes. it worked for me.

```
   with open(b'hello.txt','r') as f:
    QQ = f.read()
    #QQ = QQ.encode('utf-8')

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_xy(0, 0)
pdf.set_font('arial', 'B', 13.0)
pdf.cell(40,10,QQ)
pdf.output('Before.pdf', 'F')



pdffile = open(r"Before.pdf", "rb")
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdffile)
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pdfWriter.addPage(pdfReader.getPage(pageNum))


pdfWriter.encrypt('123')
resultPDF = open(r"After.pdf", "wb")
pdfWriter.write(resultPDF)
resultPDF.close()
pdffile.close()
```